# Replace colnames to substring of colname

Tags: r

I wonder how I I can replace the colnames of my data frame to be the unique string in the original colname?

```
> colnames(df.iso)
 [1] "../trimmed/100G.tally.fasta" "../trimmed/100R.tally.fasta" "../trimmed/106G.tally.fasta"
 [4] "../trimmed/106R.tally.fasta" "../trimmed/122G.tally.fasta" "../trimmed/122R.tally.fasta"
 [7] "../trimmed/124G.tally.fasta" "../trimmed/124R.tally.fasta" "../trimmed/126G.tally.fasta"
[10] "../trimmed/126R.tally.fasta" "../trimmed/134G.tally.fasta" "../trimmed/134R.tally.fasta"
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Depending on how regular your names are: `substr(basename(colnames), 1, 4)` or `sub('.*/(\\d+\\w)\\..*', '\\1', colnames)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `sub` with `?basename` to extract the substring from the column names.  Assign the output back to the column names to reflect the change.

```
colnames(df.iso) <- sub("\\..*", '', basename(colnames(df.iso)))
```

If we don't want to use `basename`, `sub` can also be used alone.

```
colnames(df.iso) <- sub("([^/]+/){2}([^.]+).*",
                              "\\2", colnames(df.iso))
```

Comment: why basename? never used that

Comment: @user2300940  It removes all of the path upto the the last path separator making it easy to extract the substring

Answer (score 1):

Similarly to @Akrun's second answer,

```
colnames(df.iso) <- sub("[^0-9]+([0-9]+[A-Z])\\.tal.*", "\\1", colnames(df.iso))
```

Should also do the trick. His first method is likely faster, which probably won't matter here.